# Exercise 2.1.17 from Leinster

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

[image]

1) How is $\triangle A$ defined on a morphism $ f^{op}: V\to U$? $\triangle A(f^{op})$ should be a map of sets $A\to A$. Is there only one definition that will force functoriality?

2) How should I try to solve the problem itself? I.e., what strategy should I use? There must be a lot of functors $[\mathscr O(X)^{op},\mathbf{Set}]\to\mathbf{Set}$, so potentially there are a lot of choices for $\Pi$ (and similarly for the other functors).

Comment: For a map $A\to A$, how about the identity?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown That would be the most natural choice. And I believe that not only does this define a functor $\mathscr O(X)^{op}\to\mathbf{Set}$ but also it defines a functor $\mathscr O(X)\to\mathbf{Set}$. This made me think that maybe there is some other definition which does not define a functor on $\mathscr (X)^{op}$. (If sending morphisms to identities works, why are they talking about contravariant functors instead of covariant...)

Comment: Yes, but contravariant ones are the ones relevant for discussing sheaves, etc. Anyway, yes, it is just identity maps.